# SLO compliance report according to google SRE book

Tags: performance, sli, sre

I want to create a SLO compliance report like Google SRE handbook indicated here : https://landing.google.com/sre/workbook/chapters/implementing-slos/#slo-compliance-report

As shown in the description : the numbers in parentheses indicate the number of objectives that were met, and the total number of objectives.

Problem : I couldn't figure out how they calculated the number in brackets and why the number in above few service are all 1's whereas the last service has numbers greater than 1.

I need guidance on just how to come up with these numbers. Please help

Comment: Every microservice can have more than one SLO, in this [compliance report](https://landing.google.com/sre/workbook/chapters/implementing-slos/#slo-compliance-report) for Q1 2017, the BrokenService has 9 SLOs with all of them met. All other services have only one SLO.

Please create the SLOs for your services and track them quarterly to come with a similar report.

Comment: So, are you saying that Brokenservice  had 87/123/150 SLO's really? These many SLO's for a particular quarter?

Comment: Yes, i assume it's a sample report with dummy data. It's also highly unlikely for Google services to have 1 SLO.